# I have newsfeed page where all posts will be shown i wants to get the comment value and id of this specific post on which the user comment

Tags: jquery, node.js, handlebars.js

i am developing a Social Website where i have a newsfeed page where all the posts will be shown i wants to get the comment and the id of this specific post on which the user comment.i am using Each function of Jquery but it also get the values from the input field that are empty and on which the user does not comment..

```
{{#each posts}}
<div class="form-inline" class="commentForm">
       <div class="form-group">
       <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{id}}" class="postId">
       <input class="form-control comment" type="text" placeholder="Your 
       comments" />
     </div>
<div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default set send" 
         >Add</input>
  </div> 
      </div>
           </div>               
          {{/each}}

            $(".send").click(function(){


                $('input[type="text"].comment').each(function () {

             comment = $(this).val();
($(this).val(''));


});


  $('input[type="hidden"].postId').each(function () {

    comment = $(this).val();

}
```

console.log(postidn);

```
 });
```

});

i want to get the id and comment of specific post on which the user comment by clicking the Send button..

Comment: Does your code have any JS errors in console?

Comment: no i dont have any error.

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop ..You can just use `.closest()` and `.find()`

```
$(".send").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form redirect
   var ThisForm = $(this).closest('.commentForm');   // get this parent form
   var Id = ThisForm.find('input.postId').val();     // get postId
   var Comment = ThisForm.find('input[type="text"].comment').val();  // get comment
   console.log(Id +' ||| '+ Comment);
});
```

Live example

```js
$(".send").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form redirect
   var ThisForm = $(this).closest('.commentForm');   // get this parent form
   var Id = ThisForm.find('input.postId').val();     // get postId
   var Comment = ThisForm.find('input[type="text"].comment').val();  // get comment
   console.log(Id +' ||| '+ Comment);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-inline commentForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{id}}" class="postId">
    <input class="form-control comment" type="text" placeholder="Your 
    comments" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default set send" value="Add">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @mehmoodchohan because you have two `class` property in the same element `class="form-inline commentForm"`

Comment: You're totally welcome @mehmoodchohan .. Have a great day :-)